# What better way to add new features on a project already in production?

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting, backups

We know that drupal is based on nodes.

I feel it difficult to make updates to a project already in production.

Currently I have two environments. A testing, and other production.
I make changes in the test environment, then I redo the production environment.

Is there any way I can do packages with content types, views, and maybe even taxonomy nodes, and import them into production?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for what KiamLalluno is answered in the comments.
I would just like to supply it by saying
These module have been helpfull for me when I was in your situation

[Deploy Module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy)

[GO live checklist](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-how-automate-and-control-your-go-live-checklist)

[Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush)

[Feeds Module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)

[Features Module](http://drupal.org/project/features)

[Enviroment Indicator](http://drupal.org/node/646024?no_cache=1361178253)

Hope it helps